# Excel dynamic graph range

Tags: excel, graph, dynamic, match, offset

Without using VBA macros, is it possible to dynamically set the range of a graph?

I have a table like this:

[image: ![enter image description here]

I want to now create a graph with merely the "valid" amounts of 2,3,4 and 5 as bar chart, say. These valid ranges can change however to 3,4 and 5 say. The valid numbers are always consecutive. so I just need the beginning and end.

I've looked into index, match, and offset, and I just don't get how to accomplish this exactly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

My answer in a nutshell as I have to leave in a few minutes. (I can add details later, if you are interested).

As far as I know, Excel charts do neither allow range names or formula as input, which makes it difficult to set a dynamic range without a VBA macro.

However, if you are only interested in a chart that grows and shrinks with the data, you can use a XY chart do achieve the desired result.

[image]

### Formulas:

D2: `=IF(COUNTBLANK(A2)=1,#NA,COUNTIFS(D$1:D1,">=0")+1)`

E2: `=D2`

F2: `=IF(COUNTBLANK(C2)=1,#NA,0)`

G2: `=IF(COUNTBLANK(C2)=1,#NA,C2)`

### Chart properties

- Just create the maximum number of rows (here 7)

[image]

- Set the stroke/line width to 30.
- Ajust the x-axis to start with 0.5.

*Note*: Screenshots were made with a German Excel version.

*Downsite*: The x-axis labels cannot be adjusted easily.